# How to remove nan value while combining two column in Panda Data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying but not able to remove `nan` while combining two columns of a `DataFrame`.

Data is like:

```
feedback_id                  _id
568a8c25cac4991645c287ac     nan    
568df45b177e30c6487d3603     nan    
nan                          568df434832b090048f34974       
nan                          568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1   
568df3f0832b090048f34711     nan
nan                          568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

I want:

```
feedback_request_id
568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
568df45b177e30c6487d3603
568df434832b090048f34974
568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
568df3f0832b090048f34711
568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

Here is my code:

```
df3['feedback_request_id'] = ('' if df3['_id'].empty else df3['_id'].map(str)) + ('' if df3['feedback_id'].empty else df3['feedback_id'].map(str))
```

Output I'm getting:

```
feedback_request_id
568a8c25cac4991645c287acnan
568df45b177e30c6487d3603nan
nan568df434832b090048f34974
nan568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
568df3f0832b090048f34711nan
nan568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

I have tried this, also:

```
df3['feedback_request_id'] = ('' if df3['_id']=='nan' else df3['_id'].map(str)) + ('' if df3['feedback_id']=='nan' else df3['feedback_id'].map(str))
```

But it's giving the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print df['feedback_id'].combine_first(df['_id'])
0    568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1    568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2    568df434832b090048f34974
3    568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
4    568df3f0832b090048f34711
5    568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
Name: feedback_id, dtype: object

print df['feedback_id'].fillna(df['_id'])
0    568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1    568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2    568df434832b090048f34974
3    568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
4    568df3f0832b090048f34711
5    568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
Name: feedback_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: This will only combine two columns, `bfill` is a better option

Answer (score 15):

If you want a solution that doesn't require referencing `df` twice or any of its columns explicitly:

```
df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

With two columns, this will copy non-null values from the right column into the left, then select the left column.

Comment: Will this replace nan values in the column being copied to?

Comment: This is excellent - it will handle multiple columns:   <br>
    <br>
`     COLUMN BEAM BRACE LINE`  <br>
`    C4 (3651, 3651, 1) NaN NaN NaN`    <br>
`    B58 NaN (4367, 5285, 0) NaN NaN`    <br>
`    D1027 NaN NaN (4311, 4310, 1) NaN`    <br>
`    L11 NaN NaN NaN (3686, 3677, 1)`    <br>
    <br>
->    <br>
  
`    C4       (3651, 3651, 1)`    <br>
`    B58      (4367, 5285, 0)`    <br>
`    D1027    (4311, 4310, 1)`    <br>
`    L11      (3686, 3677, 1)`    <br>
`    Name: COLUMN, dtype: object`    <br>

Execrable editing options...

Answer (score 14):

For an in-place solution, you can use [`pd.Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) with [`pd.DataFrame.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df['feedback_id'].update(df.pop('_id'))

print(df)

                feedback_id
0  568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1  568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2  568df434832b090048f34974
3  568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
4  568df3f0832b090048f34711
5  568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

Answer (score 3):

below should works, if not, check with the null in your columns are np.nan or pd.NaT, only pd.NaT will work

```
df[['col1','col2']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering OP's original dataframe `df`, the final solution would depend on the desired output type:

1. Dataframe (`Size (6,1)`)
2. Series (`Size (6,)`)

---

**Option 1**

Assuming one wants the final output to be a dataframe , one can create a dataframe after  concatenating `_id` to `feedback_id`, then dropping the NaNs, renaming the column to `feedback_request_id`, and reseting the index, as follows

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df['feedback_id'], df['_id']]).dropna(), columns=['feedback_request_id']).reset_index(drop=True)

[Out]:
        feedback_request_id
0  568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1  568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2  568df3f0832b090048f34711
3  568df434832b090048f34974
4  568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
5  568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

or using [`pandas.Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) as follows

```
df_new = pd.concat([df['feedback_id'], df['_id']]).dropna().to_frame(name='feedback_request_id').reset_index(drop=True)

[Out]:
        feedback_request_id
0  568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1  568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2  568df3f0832b090048f34711
3  568df434832b090048f34974
4  568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
5  568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

---

**Option 2**

Alternatively, if one wants the output to be a Series, the following would be enough

```
df_new = pd.concat([df['feedback_id'], df['_id']]).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)


[Out]:
0    568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1    568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2    568df3f0832b090048f34711
3    568df434832b090048f34974
4    568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
5    568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

There are other ways to do that.
Another one is using [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`pandas.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notnull.html) as follows

```
df_new = df['feedback_id'].where(df['feedback_id'].notnull(), df['_id'])

[Out]:

0    568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1    568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2    568df434832b090048f34974
3    568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
4    568df3f0832b090048f34711
5    568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```

Another one is using [`pandas.Series.combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine.html) with a custom lambda function with [`pandas.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notnull.html)

```
df_new = df['feedback_id'].combine(df['_id'], lambda x, y: x if pd.notnull(x) else y))

[Out]:
0    568a8c25cac4991645c287ac
1    568df45b177e30c6487d3603
2    568df434832b090048f34974
3    568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1
4    568df3f0832b090048f34711
5    568e5a38b4a797c664143dda
```