# Injecting values of DataFrame to NaN of Series with different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I inject values of dataframe and complement NaN of series with different length like those:

```
series             dataframe
                           0
0      NaN       0  0.468979
1      3.0       1  0.470546
2      NaN       2  0.458234
3      3.0       3  0.427878
4      NaN       4  0.494763
       ...          ...
886    NaN     682  0.458234
887    2.0     683  0.501460
888    NaN     684  0.458234
889    3.0     685  0.494949
890    NaN     686  0.427878
891    2.0
892    3.0
893    1.0
```

I need to find something that can inject values of dataframe to NaN of series like below:

```
0    0.468979  <- row0 of dataframe
1         3.0  
2    0.470546  <- row1 of dataframe
3         3.0
4    0.458234  <- row2 of dataframe
     ...
886  0.458234  <- row684 of dataframe
887       2.0
888  0.494949  <- row685 of dataframe
889       3.0
890  0.427878  <- row686 of dataframe
891       2.0
892       3.0
893       1.0
```

Actually, I can get the above result by this code:

```
j = 0
for i, c in enumerate(series):
    if np.isnan(c):
        series[i] = dataframe[0][j]
        j += 1
```

but it makes `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

How can I inject values of dataframe and complement NaN of series without the warning?

According to the previous question: [How to remove nan value while combining two column in Panda Data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989341/how-to-remove-nan-value-while-combining-two-column-in-panda-data-frame)
I tried below, however, it doesn't work well due to the different length:

```
series = series.fillna(dataframe[0])

0      0.468979  <- row0 of dataframe
1      3.000000
2      0.458234  <- row2 of dataframe
3      3.000000
4      0.494763  <- row4 of dataframe
         ...
886         NaN
887    2.000000
888         NaN
889    3.000000
890         NaN
891    2.000000
892    3.000000
893    1.000000
```

Comment: Try: `series.loc[series.isna()] = dataframe[0].values[: series.isna().sum()]`

Comment: Thank you for reply, Andrej, but it returns ```SettingWithCopyWarning```.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).