# Merge two columns into one (with NaN values)

Tags: python, merge

I have my table that looks like this:

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B |  |
| C |  |
|  | D |
|  | E |
| F |  |
|  | G |

I want it to look like this:

| column C |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
| F |
| G |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this with pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove nan value while combining two column in Panda Data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989341/how-to-remove-nan-value-while-combining-two-column-in-panda-data-frame)

Answer (score 2):

A column is major

```
df['column C'] = df['column A'].fillna(df['column B'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use pandas, you can `bfill` and get the first column:

```
df['column C'] = df[['column A', 'column B']].bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
```

output:

```
  column A column B column C
0        A      NaN        A
1        B      NaN        B
2        C      NaN        C
3      NaN        D        D
4      NaN        E        E
5        F      NaN        F
6      NaN        G        G
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that exactly what you want or its just a example but you could do something like this

This is coding from first principles

```
Column_A = ['A', "B",'C','','','F','']
Column_B = ['', "",'','D','E','','G']
Column_C = ['', "",'','','','','']

print('column C')

for i in range(len(Column_C)):
    if (Column_A[i] !='') :
        Column_C[i] = Column_A[i]
        print(Column_C[i])
    elif (Column_B[i] !='') :
        Column_C[i] = Column_B[i]
        print(Column_C[i])
```