# Fill in empty space by merging columns using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, txt

I am a Python noob. I have an unstructured text file that I'm trying to capture to a dataframe and export to excel.
I need to merge 38 to 36, 45 to 43, and 79 to 78 filling in the empty space with the data on the merging column.

Dummy Dataset

|  | 0 | 5 | 36 | 38 | 43 | 45 | 78 | 79 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01JUN2022 |  | 1.2 |  | B |  | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 01JUN2022 |  | 1.4 |  | D |  | 1.4 |
| 3 | E | 01JUN2022 | 1.5 |  | F |  | 1.6 |  |
| 4 | G | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 |  | H |  | 1.7 |  |
| 5 | I | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 |  | J |  | 1.8 |  |
| 6 | K | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 |  | L |  | 1.3 |  |
| 1 | A | 01JUN2022 |  | 1.2 |  | B |  | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 01JUN2022 |  | 1.4 | D |  | 1.4 |  |
| 3 | E | 01JUN2022 |  | 1.5 | F |  | 1.6 |  |
| 4 | G | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 |  | H |  | 1.7 |  |
| 5 | I | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 |  |  | J |  | 1.8 |
| 6 | K | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 |  | L |  |  | 1.3 |

Required output

|  | 0 | 5 | 36 | 43 | 79 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01JUN2022 | 1.2 | B | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | D | 1.4 |
| 3 | E | 01JUN2022 | 1.5 | F | 1.6 |
| 4 | G | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 | H | 1.7 |
| 5 | I | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | J | 1.8 |
| 6 | K | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 | L | 1.3 |
| 1 | A | 01JUN2022 | 1.2 | B | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | D | 1.4 |
| 3 | E | 01JUN2022 | 1.5 | F | 1.6 |
| 4 | G | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 | H | 1.7 |
| 5 | I | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | J | 1.8 |
| 6 | K | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 | L | 1.3 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove nan value while combining two column in Panda Data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989341/how-to-remove-nan-value-while-combining-two-column-in-panda-data-frame)

Comment: I tried all the answers in that but I did not get the required output

Comment: Is it guaranteed that only 1 of the 2 columns being merged will have a value present? i.e is it possible for both columns to hold a value for the same row?

Comment: Yes only one column will have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would start by converting `''` to `NaN` as follows

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Then one can use [`pandas.Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html)

```
df['36'] = df['36'].combine_first(df['38'])
df['43'] = df['43'].combine_first(df['45'])
df['79'] = df['79'].combine_first(df['78'])

[Out]:
    id  0          5   36   38 43   45   78   79
0    1  A  01JUN2022  1.2  1.2  B    B  NaN  1.2
1    2  C  01JUN2022  1.4  1.4  D    D  NaN  1.4
2    3  E  01JUN2022  1.5  NaN  F  NaN  1.6  1.6
3    4  G  01JUN2022  1.7  NaN  H  NaN  1.7  1.7
4    5  I  01JUN2022  1.4  NaN  J  NaN  1.8  1.8
5    6  K  01JUN2022  1.7  NaN  L  NaN  1.3  1.3
6    1  A  01JUN2022  1.2  1.2  B    B  NaN  1.2
7    2  C  01JUN2022  1.4  1.4  D  NaN  1.4  1.4
8    3  E  01JUN2022  1.5  1.5  F  NaN  1.6  1.6
9    4  G  01JUN2022  1.7  NaN  H  NaN  1.7  1.7
10   5  I  01JUN2022  1.4  NaN  J    J  NaN  1.8
11   6  K  01JUN2022  1.7  NaN  L  NaN  NaN  1.3
```

Finally, one can drop the columns that one doesn't want or select the one's to display as follows

```
df = df[['0', '5', '36', '43', '79']]

[Out]:

    0          5   36 43   79
0   A  01JUN2022  1.2  B  1.2
1   C  01JUN2022  1.4  D  1.4
2   E  01JUN2022  1.5  F  1.6
3   G  01JUN2022  1.7  H  1.7
4   I  01JUN2022  1.4  J  1.8
5   K  01JUN2022  1.7  L  1.3
6   A  01JUN2022  1.2  B  1.2
7   C  01JUN2022  1.4  D  1.4
8   E  01JUN2022  1.5  F  1.6
9   G  01JUN2022  1.7  H  1.7
10  I  01JUN2022  1.4  J  1.8
11  K  01JUN2022  1.7  L  1.3
```

and this gives the desired output.

---

**Notes:**

- There are additional ways to remove `NaN` and combine the columns. For that, see: [How to remove nan value while combining two column in Panda Data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34989341/7109869)
- There are also additional ways to delete columns in Python. If one wants to learn more about it, see: [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13411544/7109869)